# Determining the region of integration

Tags: probability, multivariable-calculus

Consider the following probability density function that models a joint distribution between $X$ and $Y$,

$$f(x,y) = \left\{\begin{array}{ll}
g(x,y) & \mbox{ if } 0.4\leq x \leq 0.6, \; 0.10 \leq y \leq 0.30, \;0 \leq x + y \leq 1,\\
0 & \mbox{ elsewhere}, 
\end{array}
\right.$$

for some $g(x,y)$ that makes this a valid PDF.

I am having trouble sketching the support region and then determining the bounds of integration. For example, I wish to find $P(X \leq 0.5, Y \leq 0.2)$.

My issue is that this region will define a box. So I am unsure what is the purpose of the condition for $0 \leq x + y \leq 1$. What will the regions of integration look like for $P(X \leq 0.5, Y \leq 0.2)$? Is it simply that I will integrate from $x = 0.4$ to $x = 0.5$, and then integrate from $y = 0.10$ to $y = 0.20$? The picture seems to indicate this, but then I am confused as to the purpose of $0 \leq x + y \leq 1$.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your probability density function $f(x,y)$ that models a joint distribution between random variables $X$ and $Y$ is:

$$f(x,y) = \left\{\begin{array}{ll}
g(x,y) & \mbox{ if } 0.4\leq x \leq 0.6, \; 0.10 \leq y \leq 0.30, \;0 \leq x + y \leq 1,\\
0 & \mbox{ otherwise}, 
\end{array}
\right.$$
where $g(x,y)$ is some function that makes $f$ a valid PDF, then 
$$
P(X\leq 0.5, Y\leq 0.2) = \int_{0.1}^{0.2} \int_{0.4}^{0.5} g(x,y) \, dx\,dy. 
$$
I would consider $0\leq x+y \leq 1$ as an extraneous condition on $f$.